# Parametrization of a unit 2 sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Here is the parametrization for a unit 2 sphere locating at the center of a Euclidean 3 dimensional space:

$$x=x(u,v)= \cos u\sin v,\ \ y=y(u,v)=\sin u\sin v,\ \ z=z(u,v)=\cos v, $$

where $0\leq u<2\pi,0\leq v<\pi$. I'm not sure if the inverse $u=u(x,y,z),v=v(x,y,z)$ exists. If it does, then how can one find out its exact form? In addition, it's obvious that expression such as: $e_{x}=\frac{\partial u(x,y,z)}{\partial x}e_u+\frac {\partial v(x,y,z)}{\partial x}e_v$ is meaningless at at least some point on the unit sphere if we can draw a picture. But how can one show this fact in a formal way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$x=x(u,v)= \cos u\sin v; \ y=y(u,v)=\sin u\sin v; \ z=z(v)=\cos v. $$

Mapping is bijective.

For given latitude and longitude (u,v) respectively a single point on sphere (x,y,z) is defined.

For given point on sphere (x,y,z) a single latitude and a single longitude (u,v) are defined thus:

$$ u=\tan^{-1}\frac {y}{ x}; v=\cos^{-1} z. $$

With $ \tan^{-1}$ function proper quadrant has to be chosen.

Comment: What is the longitude of the north pole?

Comment: @lhf: Indeterminate as a singular point on surface, but exists if approach longitude is given.

Comment: It is NOT a bijection. Specifically, It is not an injection. Consider v=0 and u can be any value. Then it maps to the same point (0, 0, 1).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y}{x}=\tan u\qquad u=\arctan\frac{y}{x},\qquad v=\arccos z$$
Warning: $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ is actually [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).